# NodeMCU tmr.alarm always returns false

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I have a problem with NodeMCU, trying to start a tmr.alarm on a esp8266.

tmr.alarm never starts the timer, and always returns false.
I've tried changing the timer, and even changing the type of the alarm (AUTO, SINGLE...) but i always have the same result.

Here's part of the code, i'm trying to comunicate with a DS18B20 (OneWire temperature sensor) once every 5 seconds or so.

```
if not tmr.alarm(1, 5000, tmr.ALARM_AUTO, function() 
      -- Comunication with the sensor
    end)
then print("Comunication with DS18B20 couldn't be started.") end
```

The output is always

```
Comunication with DS18B20 couldn't be started.
```

Comment: Your code is pretty much [straight from the book](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/modules/tmr/#tmralarm), looks ok. What firmware do you use (version, modules)? Do you have other timers running, possibly on the same ID?

Comment: No other timers running, NodeMCU version 0.9.5
Perhaps a firmware update would be handy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the old 0.9.x NodeMCU binaries from https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/releases they're no longer supported and contain lots of bugs. [Build a custom firmware](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/build/) from the `dev` or `master` branch.

I'm not aware of any timer bugs in recent versions.

Comment: Thank your for your help. The software is now running smoothly, and the custom build consumes less memory than the other i had.